# Finding function pointer if the Java_... naming is not used

Tags: android, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

I'm debugging an android application and am confusing about one android shared library and here i wanna explain the problem.

There is a native function defined in java code (java side) like this:

```
public static native void nativeInitialize();
```

Package:

```
package com.example.ExClass;
```

I loaded the shared library in IDA Pro.
I thought that i can find that function in exported functions and it should be something like this `Java_com_example_ExClass_nativeInitialize`
But the function is not in export list and as i debugged the java side codes, i know the function is calling from java but i don't know how it is working ?!

Comment: It is possible the library uses the [`RegisterNatives`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17734) approach to associate method names with function pointers. Try searching for structs that embed of the string "nativeInitialize". Alternatively, look through the `JNI_OnLoad` function for other clues.

Comment: @Botje Thanks bro, i know what you are talking about but i searched ```RegisterNatives``` in strings list , import table, and also it's raw text and assembly, but nothing found. It is not unusual ??

Comment: RegisterNatives is part of the gigantic function table behind the `JNIEnv` struct. On my system it is the 215th entry, or offset 1720 from the start. In assembly it will look like `ldr x4, [x8,#1720]` followed by `br x4`

Comment: @Botje Thanks bro, please submit an answer i wanna mark it as "Answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name-mangling scheme (Java_...) is not used, then it is possible the library uses the [RegisterNatives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17734) approach to associate method names with function pointers. Try searching for structs that embed the string "nativeInitialize", they should be the `methods` argument to RegisterNatives. Look through the `JNI_OnLoad` function for the call site.

On Aarch64 assembly it should look like:

```
ldr x4, [x8,#1720] # RegisterNatives is the 215th member, times 8 bytes per pointer
bl  x4             # Could also be a br if this was the last call of the function
```